# query table with two where cases

Tags: php, sql, laravel

i have a table of tickets there's a column for totals where i want to find the totals of the event id from form and the user email from input form and sum them

here's the store function

```php
$ticket=new Ticket;
$ticket->userName= $request->input('userName');
$ticket->userEmail= $request->input('userEmail');
$ticket->phoneNumber= $request->input('phoneNumber');
$ticket->regular_quantity= $request->input('regular_quantity');
$ticket->vip_quantity= $request->input('vip_quantity');
$ticket->event_id=$request->route('id');
$ticket->total= $request->input('regular_quantity') + $request->input('vip_quantity');
```

heres the query

```php
$tt=DB::table('tickets')->where('userEmail''=' $ticket->userEmail,'id' '=' $ticket->event_id)->sum('total');
```

it contains a syntax error where am i wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
      $tt=DB::table('tickets')->where('userEmail','=', $ticket->userEmail)->where('id', '=', $ticket->event_id)->sum('total');
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

this way

```
 $tt=DB::table('tickets')->where('userEmail','=', $ticket->userEmail)
->where('id' , '=' , $ticket->event_id)
->sum('total');
```

for more
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries